# JavaScript event handlers -why no alert?

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie at JavaScript trying to learn event handlers. Looking at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/uV4kv/  can anyone tell me why the pop up is not appearing when the link is clicked?

I've also copied the code below

```
<a href="#" title="click me" id="clickLink">click me</a>


function addEventHandler(oNode, sEvt, fFunc, bCaptures){
    if (typeof(window.event) != "undefined")
        oNode.attachEvent("on"+sEvt, fFunc);
    else
        oNode.addEventListener(sEvt,fFunc,bCaptures);
}

function onLinkClicked(e) {
    alert("you clicked the link");
}
function setUpClickHandler(){
    addEventHanlder(document.getElementById('clickLink'), "click", onLinkClicked, false);
}

addEventHandler(window,"load",setUpClickHandler,false);
```

Comment: I get the error: *Uncaught ReferenceError: setUpClickHandler is not defined*

Comment: There's a typo in `addEventHanlder`

Comment: @Pekka: There's more than one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically three problems:

- You have some typos, e.g. "Hanlder" instead of "Handler" and "Sevt" instead of "sEvt".
- The code is already run after page load, so the event handler you add to `window` will never be called. Change in jsFiddle from `onLoad` to `no wrap (head)`.
- You "IE detection" does not work. I get this error in Chrome:

  > Uncaught TypeError: Object `http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/#` has no method `'attachEvent'`.

  Better would be to test whether the function `window.attachEvent` exists. I also think that `window.event` is only available when an event is raised.

If this is corrected, [your code will run (DEMO)](http://jsfiddle.net/uV4kv/1/).

---

**Further notes:**

Testing which method is supported (i.e. `attachEvent` or `addEventListener`) on every call of your function is unnecessary. It won't change during the life of the page. Better is to test only *once* at the beginning. Example:

```
var addEventHandler = (function() {
    if(window.attachEvent) {
        return function(oNode, sEvt, fFunc) {
            oNode.attachEvent("on"+sEvt, fFunc);
        };
    }
    else {
        return function(oNode, sEvt, fFunc, bCaptures) {
            oNode.addEventListener(sEvt,fFunc,bCaptures);
        };
    }
}());
```

This assigns a function the supported function to `addEventHandler`.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of problems:

- You have a recurring typo, "Hanlder" instead of "Handler". There are at least two, one where you do your `setUpClickHanlder` (sic) function, and one within it (`addEventHanlder`).
- Also, you have "Sevt" where you mean "sEvt". (JavaScript is case sensitive.)

[Let tools help you](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html). Use a browser that gives you a console showing errors. Use a debugger for single-stepping through code, looking at variable values at runtime with inspectors, etc.

Comment: thanks for the debugger recommendation, but I find them very confusing. If you happen to know a good tutorial that explains the debugging process step by step (and how to interpret the data) then please recommend. Cheers.

Comment: @Michael: I don't know of any, but a quick search suggests that they're out there. For instance, the Chrome team has videos and such: http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/ Of course, Visual Studio.Net has a huge community around it, I'm sure people have written up how to use it. Firebug (a debugger for Firefox) has a wiki (I have no idea how good it is): http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 1):

Your addEventHandler needs adustment:

```
function addEventHandler(oNode, sEvt, fFunc, bCaptures) {
    oNode.attachEvent ? oNode.attachEvent ("on" + sEvt, fFunc) :
                        oNode.addEventListener (sEvt, fFunc, bCaptures);
}
```

It is in event handlers themselves that you need to check for window.event

Comment: True, although his version would mostly work most of the time. It's not the actual problem here, though.

Comment: thanks, but I don't see any real difference between the code in your answer and the code in OP. Aren't I checking for window event in my addEventHandler function?